# Intuiting factorials in recurrence relations

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, factorial

I'm trying to solve differential equations via series, and I understand the underlying concepts and processes to get to a recurrence relation. For example, from a homogeneous differential equation, I can reach an relation such as $$ a_n = - \frac{a_{n-2}}{n(3n +1)} \ \text{where} \ a_{3, 5, 7...} = 0  $$

My method to try and find the answer so far has been to write out large-ish terms without simplifying and look for a pattern by inspection
$$ a_6 = \frac{-1}{2(7)*4(13)*6(19)} $$
I haven't had much luck. I can find some terms that appear in the final answer, but there always seems to be at the least a factorial function that goes unaccounted for. 
My textbook says that the answer to this recurrence relation is
$$ a_m = \frac{(-1)^m}{2^m m!7*13* ... (6m+1)} $$

I can evaluate this and show that it is equivalent to my recurrence relation, but I don't know what steps to take to get to that point. I'm especially baffeled by how the factorial $m!$ and $2^m$ fit into the answer. Any clarification would be appreciated.

---

It was suggested in the comments that I think of the problem in terms of $ a_n = (something)a_{n-2} = (something)a_{n-4} $
That makes the function
$$ a_n = - \frac{a_{n-6}}{n(n-2)(n-4)(3n+1)(3n-5)(3n - 11)} $$
I can see a likely candidate for a factorial function in the $ n(n-2)(n-4) $ sequence, and the other three terms in the denominator decrease by 6 in each term, but I don't have any ideas for how to turn these patterns into an actual function.

Comment: Run the recurrence using $n$ instead of a specific number. That is, try writing down $a_n = (something) a_{n-2} = (something) a_{n-4} = (something) a_{n-6}$ etc. until you notice a pattern.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  I hadn't thought to do that before, so I edited the question further. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Lets $\ds{b_{n} \equiv a_{2n} = -\,{a_{2n - 2} \over 2n\pars{6n + 1}}
> \implies
> b_{n} = -\,{b_{n - 1} \over 2n\pars{6n + 1}}}$

\begin{align}
b_{n} & = -\,{1 \over 2}\,{b_{n - 1} \over n\pars{6n + 1}} =
{\pars{-1}^{2} \over 2^{2}}
\,{b_{n - 2} \over n\pars{6n + 1}\pars{n - 1}\bracks{6\pars{n - 1} + 1}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{-1}^{3} \over 2^{3}}
\,{b_{n - 3} \over n\pars{6n + 1}\pars{n - 1}\bracks{6\pars{n - 1} + 1}
\pars{n - 2}\bracks{6\pars{n - 2} + 1}}
\\[5mm] & = \cdots =
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 2^{n}}\,{1 \over n\pars{n - 1}\ldots 1}\,
{1 \over \prod_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{6k + 1}}\,b_{0} =
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 2^{n}}\,{1 \over n!}\,
{1 \over 6^{n}\prod_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{k + 1/6}}\,b_{0}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 12^{n}}\,{1 \over n!}\,
{1 \over {\vphantom{\Large A}\pars{7/6}^{\,\large \overline{n}}}}\,b_{0} =
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 12^{n}}\,{1 \over n!}\,
{1 \over \Gamma\pars{7/6 +n}/\Gamma\pars{7/6}}\,b_{0}\qquad
\pars{~\Gamma: Gamma\ Function~}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 12^{n}}\,{\pars{1/6}! \over n!\pars{1/6 + n}!}\,b_{0}}
\qquad\mbox{where}\ z! = \Gamma\pars{z + 1}.
\end{align}

> Note that $\ds{a^{\overline{m}} = a\pars{a + 1}\pars{a + m - 1}}$,
>   with $\ds{m \in \mathbb{N}_{\ >\ 0}}$ and $\ds{a^{\overline{0}} = 1}$, is the
>   [Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) which can be expressed in terms of the *Gamma Function* as follows: $\ds{a^{\overline{m}} =
> {\Gamma\pars{a + m} \over \Gamma\pars{a}}}$. 'Extension' of the raising factorial to any $\ds{m \in \mathbb{Z}}$ can be seen in the above cited link.

Comment: I think that a reference to the properties of the gamma function that lets you introduce it would be useful.

Comment: @martycohen I just added some notes about 'raising factorial', relation between $\Gamma$ and the factorial. Thanks for your remark.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to derive $$a_{2m}=\frac{(-1)^m}{2^m m!7*13* ... (6m+1)}a_0$$ since $a_n=0$ for odd indices $n$. The patterns that develop are pretty clear:

$$a_{2m}=\color{blue}{\frac{-1}{2m(6m+1)}a_{2m-2}}$$

$$=\frac{-1}{2m(6m+1)}\cdot \frac{-1}{2(m-1)(6(m-1)+1)}a_{2(m-1)-2}=\color{blue}{\frac{(-1)^2}{2^2[m(m-1)]\cdot[(6m+1)(6m-5)]}a_{2m-2.2}}$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^2}{2^2[m(m-1)]\cdot[(6m+1)(6m-5)]}\cdot\frac{-1}{2(m-2)(6(m-2)+1)}a_{2(m-2)-2}=\color{blue}{\frac{(-1)^3}{2^3[m(m-1)(m-2)]\cdot[(6m+1)(6m-5)(6m-11)]}a_{2m-2.3}}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$=\color{blue}{\frac{(-1)^m}{2^m[m(m-1)\cdots(m-(m-1))]\cdot[(6m+1)(6m-5)\cdots(6(m-(m-1))+1)]}a_{2m-2m}}$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^m}{2^m[m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots3\cdot2\cdot1]\cdot[(6m+1)(6m-5)(6m-11)\cdots13\cdot7]}a_0$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^m}{2^mm!(6m+1)(6m-5)(6m-11)\cdots13\cdot7}a_0$$